# How to force Linq to join tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using EF 4.1 and a database I didn't design. I have two tables

```
TableA
[
  TableAKey,
  OtherField
]

TableB
[
  TableBKey,
  TableAKey, <-- Foreign Key
  OtherField
]
```

The problem I have is that the foreign key does not get nulled when the parent record is deleted.  This is something I have no control over and can't change.  When selecting from TableB I want to exclude all the rows with missing TableA records.

In SQL this is easy with a simple INNER JOIN.  However the linq below doesn't join the tables.  I guess it's optimising the SQL.  The below code generates SQL that has no mention of TableA.  Maybe because I don't return anything from it.

```
(from b in TableB
join a in TableA on b.TableAKey equals a.TableAKey
where b.OtherField == something
select b).ToList();
```

Is there any way to force a SQL join or a better way of doing this.

Cheers

Comment: "The problem I have is that the foreign key does not get nulled when the parent record is deleted." So it's not a Foreign Key constraint, then? Also I think you've already hit the answer yourself - try adding something from A into the select so it has to join.

Comment: @Tridus this does work cheers.  Yoann found a cleaner solution where I don't return unneeded values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and this :

```
var qa = from a in TableA
         select a.id;
var q= from b in TableB
       where qa.Contains(b.TableAKey)
```

it should result in a :

```
Select * from MyTable where idA in (Select id from tableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

the generated sql depends alot on your db provider...
try

```
(from a in TableA
from b in TableB
where b.OtherField == something && a.TableAKey == b.TableAKey select b).ToList();
```